# Load more products not working in porto theme magento 2 on category page

Tags: magento2

I want infinite scrolling of product on category page but load more not working. I'm using porto theme.
Referece: https://prnt.sc/qvimev

Comment: Did you managed to get this fixed? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Yes i have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
require(["jquery"], function($) {
var url = $('.next').attr('href');
if (typeof url === "undefined") {
$('#load-more-product').html('');
}
$('#load-more-product-link').on('click', function() {
var url = $('.next').attr('href');
$('#load-more-product').hide();
$('#load-more-loader').show();
$.get(url, function(data) {
$('#load-more-loader').hide();
$('#load-more-product').show();
var result = $(data).find('.item.product.product-item');
var nxtUrl = $(data).find('.next').attr('href');
result.each(function(index, value) {
$('.products.list.items.product-items').append(value);
$("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();
});
if (typeof nxtUrl === "undefined") {
$('#load-more-product').html('<em>No More product in this Category.</em>');
} else {
$('.next').attr('href', nxtUrl);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load More Infinite scroll is depends on Mageplaza Extension . so you need to make sure that Porto theme Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation Extension should be enabled